# MVC Core DateTime on Linux vs Windows

Tags: asp.net-core

When running an aspnet core app in docker via a linux host the `DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.UtcNow` are equal. Why? I stored my dates in UTC and use LocalTime to format the date. Cant do that now if app is hosted in Linux.

Linux Output:
`DateTime.Now - DateTime.UtcNow`

> {-00:00:00.1670254}

Windows Output:
`DateTime.Now - DateTime.UtcNow`

> {System.TimeSpan}
>
> Days: 0
>
> Hours: -4
>
> Milliseconds: -12
>
> Minutes: 0
>
> Seconds: 0
>
> Ticks: -144000129747
>
> TotalDays: -0.16666681683680554
>
> TotalHours: -4.0000036040833331
>
> TotalMilliseconds: -14400012.9747
>
> TotalMinutes: -240.00021624500002
>
> TotalSeconds: -14400.0129747

Comment: If the machine's timezone is UTC, why shouldn't they be the same? What *is* the Linux machine's timezone? Local means local to the machine, not local to the end user or developer. It doesn't matter that you are using Linux or Docker. If you deployed on a hosted Windows machine that's set at UTC, you'd get the same behaviour

Comment: Why do you want to use local time? Storage, scheduling can be done just as easily using UTC, although it's better to use DateTimeOffset and avoid assumptions. Local time is useful when you want to display values to users or export data in a specific timezone. Just like formatting, that's best left to the UI/export functions

Comment: I'm using local time to display the date. They are displayed differently between windows host and linux. How do I set the timezone when the host is linux so, ToLocalTime works as expected?

Comment: *Don't* use DateTime and LocalTime. It's as simple as that. There's no difference between Windows and Linux. Two different Windows machines with different timezones will refer to different times for the same "Loca" time value. If you use a hoster that provides Windows VM the timezone will *still* be set at UTC

Comment: Hosters always use UTC unless specifically asked to change the setting. With *web applications* though that wouldn't be very smart, as *clients* can come from multiple timezones. It wouldn't be very nice to display a "local" time that's 1 or 2 hours off. Use DateTimeOffset or DateTime at UTC and only convert to the *end user's local time* for display purposes